# Programmatically add/remove component with animation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, and cannot really find any good and clean answer to this question.

In a component I have a few buttons and a list ('li').
When a button is clicked it should create and add an instance of another component to the list. The different buttons should add different components.

I've successfully managed to add new instances via the componentFactoryResolver, but are having a hard time animating them the they are created or removed.

What would be a "correct" way (as the Angular team intended it) to dynamically add and remove components and animating it?

Comment: I would be happy to know why this post got minus votes, as that would help me to modify the question and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is navigation using `Router`.
I created a plunker here: https://embed.plnkr.co/sukXA2zRV7kEAq4MZDXY/

When you click A, an instance of Component A is created and added to the DOM and when you click B, the instance of A is gone and an instance of Component B is created.

HostComponent is the component where it has child routes defined. Notice how in the component, you don't actually reference any of these "child" components at all. The parent child route relationship is defined inside the app-routing.module.ts.

I recommend taking the time to read the Router guide from start to finish as this is one of the key aspects of developing in Angular 2:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Good luck!

**EDIT** Added route animation for ComponentA and updated plunker link.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! But I'm not entirely sure if I want the router to handle the component change (because of browser history and moving logic from the component to a very general place). The animation does not work for me either, and this does not add the components to the list, just switches between them. Sorry, but if you know any answer to this, I will gladly make your answer the accepted one.